# Django Error: 'Reverse for 'guestlist' with arguments '('',)' not found.'

Tags: python, html, django

I'll start off by saying that I know that this question comes up a lot, but I wasn't able to find a solution in other topics.

I'm getting this error while trying to load a page.

The relevant views:

```
def index(request):
    all_lists = GuestList.objects.all()
    guest_list = GuestList()
    for glist in all_lists:
        guest_list = glist
    return render(request, 'guestlist/base.html', {'guest_list': guest_list})


def guestlist(request, list_id):
    g_list = get_object_or_404(GuestList, pk=list_id)
    return render(request, 'guestlist/guestlist.html', {'g_list': g_list})
```

guestlist/urls.py:

```
app_name = 'guestlist'

urlpatterns = [

    # /guestlist/
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    # /guestlist/#/
    url(r'^(?P<list_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.guestlist, name='guestlist'),
    # /guestlist/#/isclose/
    url(r'^(?P<list_id>[0-9]+)/isclose/$', views.isclose, name='isclose'),
]
```

The HTML fragment that the error occurs at:

The template:

```html
{% load staticfiles %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>{% block title %} SitDown {% endblock %}</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'guestlist/style.css' %}"/>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abel|Galdeano" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Header -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#topNavBar">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>

            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'guestlist:index' %}">Sit Down</a>
        </div>

        <!-- Items -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="topNavBar">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="{% url 'guestlist:guestlist' guest_list.id %}">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt" aria-hidden="true"></span>&nbsp;
                        Guest List
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="">
                    <a href="#">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th" aria-hidden="true"></span>&nbsp;
                        Seating
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="">
                    <a href="#">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check" aria-hidden="true"></span>&nbsp;
                        Checklist
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="">
                    <a href="#">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>&nbsp;
                        Help
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search" method="get" action="#">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="q" value="">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn default">Search</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
{% block body %}

{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

Everything seems to be in order. The id is passed and it gets to the function 'guestlist()' like it should but i still get the error.

The view 'index()' renders 'base.html', which the exception occurs at.

Edit:

It seems that when I hardcode the list id like this: `<a href="{% url 'guestlist:guestlist' 2 %}">` it works. But when i do it dynamically it doesn't. I checked the variable and both if the instances provide the same url.

Comment: There's no point posting an "HTML fragment". What template is this part of? Which view is rendering it? And also note that your index view makes absolutely no sense at all; what value do you think you're sending to the template there?

Comment: Edited. Also, I'm aware that the index is redundant, but I was working with a tutorial and that's it said. I'm still experimenting with Django and learning it.

Comment: You still haven't posted enough information. Where is the rest of that template? In particular, where does `guest_list` come from there? Do you have some kind of for loop - if so, *post it*. (And I didn't say the index view was redundant, far from it, just that the code makes no sense as it is.)

Comment: Edited again. And `guest_list` comes from the `index()`view.

Comment: have you checked if your `all_lists` is empty?

Comment: I have, and it's not empty. What I want is to show the guest list. It worked when I tried other ways but I'm trying to make it work by clicking a specific button.

Comment: edit your url tag to this `<a href="{% url 'guestlist:guestlist' list_id= guest_list.id %}">`

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't work.

Comment: It seems that when I hardcode the list id like this: `<a href="{% url 'guestlist:guestlist' 2 %}">` it works.
But when i do it dynamically it doesn't. I checked the variable and both if the instances provide the same url.

Answer (score 0):

1) According to your question title that means `GuestList` model doesn't have any entry.

2) Always use `\d+` in url regex for digit match like: `(?P<list_id>\d+)`

Answer (score 0):

in HTML, as you are passing a list of `guestlist` you have to iterate over it
Eg:

```
def index(request):
    guest_list = GuestList.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'guestlist/base.html', {'guest_list': guest_list})
```

and in HTML page

```
<body>
{% for guest in guest_list %}  <-- Start LOOP
    <a href="{% url 'guestlist:guestlist' guest.id %}"> <--- Individual Guest ID
{% endfor %}   <-- End LOOP
</body>
```

Now you can get individual ID and pass it along url to your respective `guestlist` view view, if this is what you want.

Comment: I have a page that works fine and prints the guests in the list. The problem is that it is not getting the list itself. that is why i iterated over it in the index view and passed it to base.html

Comment: to access each `guest_id` you have to iterate.

Comment: To get the whole list, `guest_list` is already a list of guests.